# Is it possible to remove weird noise which increases with volume?

Tags: audio-recording, noise-reduction

I am totally newbie in topic of audio-video recording. Usually I got no problems with recording meetups using Go-Pro clone camera with built-in microphone but this time something weird happened with audio input. I have uploaded a sample to few sound hosting sites to give a view what is an issue. I tried to remove it using Audacity but this "noise" increases with input volume, especially when voice occurs. I would like to put recordings on YouTube but with such broken audio I am not sure if it's worth. Can anyone, at least, give me a tip how to deal with this?

Sample:

[host 1](https://clyp.it/055coxrs)

[host 2](http://picosong.com/QQ34)

Comment: I think your only choise is to get a better camera. Even some older versions of _real_ Go-Pro's had audio problems, IIRC.

Comment: There are many DAW/softwares that you can reduce noises.
Some engineers just use EQ plugins.

Some of my client send me the audio files with a bunch of noises. For me, I usually reduce noises by using noise capture tool in adobe audition which is less work and very fast. Check out this tutorial ( https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-_JGy6fWeY )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are programs that can do it but they only work to a point. The best solution is to record with a little higher audio levels then turn it down. This will make the audio sound better and also using an external mic would help like Rode mic. Hope it helps.